# getting error while trying to import pouchdb in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pouchdb

I have installed pouchdb and PyQt5 using pip . When i try to

```
import pouchdb
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pouchdb\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pouchdb import context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pouchdb\context.py", line 73, in <module>
    class Page(QtWebKitWidgets.QWebPage):
NameError: name 'QtWebKitWidgets' is not defined
```

What do i do to install pouchdb properly ?

Comment: the error sitll persists

Answer (score 1):

You may have installed `python-pyqt5.qtwebkit`, when you actually needed to download `python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`

This is what solved the issue for me